# Is it possible to create a A2DP/HSP client in Java?

Tags: java, bluetooth

I recently sarted working with bluetooth devices in Java with the target to build a programm, which can stream music from a smartphone app (e.g. Spotify, Google music player, VLC for Android, ...) to a PC/Laptop.

For communication with bluetooth devices I use [bluecove](http://bluecove.org/).

The pairing works fine, but I can't find a possibility to create a A2DP or HSP client. According [to a thread I found on google code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/bluecove-users/CBhZ0cfyMSA/ZvtvfL4ECLcJ) this is because bluecove (or JSR-82 implementations in general) doesn't support "audio streaming".

Am I out of luck with java for this project? Or is there another possibility to stream music from a smartphone to a PC/Laptop via bluetooth?